# running problems when trying to install hdf5 package using npm

Tags: node.js, npm, hdf5, node-gyp

```
hdf5@0.3.3 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/hdf5
node-gyp rebuild --jobs max
```

> gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission
>   denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hdf5/build' gyp ERR! System
>   Darwin 17.7.0 gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node"
>   "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild" "--jobs" "max" gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/hdf5
>   gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.3 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2 gyp ERR! not ok
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! hdf5@0.3.3 install:
>   `node-gyp rebuild --jobs max` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR!
>   Failed at the hdf5@0.3.3 install script. npm ERR! This is probably not
>   a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /Users/abc/.npm/_logs/2018-07-20T21_24_19_576Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

Your error clearly says: **Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir** which is a permissions issue. Looks likes it trying to create directory called `build` inside `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/hdf5/`.

To fix it, just run the same command with `sudo` at the beginning.

But, I would not recommend it unless you install global package.
Do you try to install a local package ? if so, make sure the permissions of the `node_modules` is not root. If it does, either `chown` it or remove it and do `npm install` with non-root user.